# Node-REDのデバッグノードに長いデータを表示させたい

Tags: bluemix

Node-REDのエディターでAPIの返り値をdebugノードに出力して確認しながら開発しています。データが大量だとdebugウインドウに表示しきれず、データが途中で切れてしまいます。全データを見たいときはどうすればいいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

debugに表示させるのではなくデータを見るのが目的ならNoSQL DBに入れるとか。後からパースして使うにもいったんDBに入れておくと好都合です。

Comment: [Qiitaの記事](http://qiita.com/joeartsea/items/3bf1fa22e088640c7624)に設定方法がでていました。settings.jsで設定するみたいです。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえずデータの内容を参照するだけでよければ、コンソールに出力するという方法もあります。

まずdebugノードの編集ウィンドウの「to」の項目に `debug tab and console` を指定します。その上でCloud FoundryのCLIで `cf logs <app name>` を実行すると debugタブでは省略されてしまう情報もすべて表示されます。

Cloud FoundryのCLIは下記URLよりダウンロードできます。
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#downloads

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix をお使いの場合は、starter code がダウンロードできると思いますが、
bluemix-settings.js ファイルに以下の記述があると思います。

```
var settings = module.exports = {
   uiPort: process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 1880,
   mqttReconnectTime: 15000,
   serialReconnectTime: 15000,
   debugMaxLength: 1000,
```

ここの debugMaxLength を適切な値に設定すると Debug メッセージの長さが変更できます。修正後は、"cf push"　にて再度 Bluemix にデプロイします。

その他のパラメータ詳細に関しては、次のURLを参照してください。

なお個人的には、Node.log() / console.log() 等も併用しています。